# MS Access: Numbering in queries

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

It is necessary to make the numbering in the queries, it should just be displayed independently of other data.
An example of code that is not particularly needed here.

```
SELECT Left([ФИО],InStr([ФИО]," ")-1) AS f,  
   Mid([ФИО],InStr([ФИО],"")+1,InStrRev([ФИО]," ")-InStr([ФИО]," ")-1) AS i, 
   Mid([ФИО],InStrRev([ФИО]," ")+1) AS o
   FROM ["Администрация"]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an ordering that you care about?  If so, it is not obvious.

Comment: MS Access does not natively support row-numbering in SQL queries. You can do it in application-code though, of course.

Comment: Maybe [this example](https://www.599cd.com/tips/access/140703-row-number/)?

Comment: Row number can easily be calculated in textbox on report using RunningSum property.